# Output is not showing for second array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, output, java.util.scanner, println

I'm a beginner in Java programming and I created a program that accepts 10 numbers as input from users and prints them. The first section is using for loop and the second section is using while loop. The first section works properly and the second section isn't displaying output. Could anybody help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayOfTenElements {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int numArray1[] = new int [10];
    int numArray2[] = new int [10];
    int i;

    //First Section
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        numArray1[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("The entered numbers are: ");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.print(numArray1[i] + " ");
    }
    
    //Second Section
    System.out.println("\nEnter 10 numbers: ");
    int j = 0;
    while(j<10) {
        numArray2[j] = scanner.nextInt();
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println("The entered numbers are: ");
    while(j<10) {
        System.out.print(numArray2[j] + " ");
        j++;
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

}

Comment: did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @OldProgrammer No, I didn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not resetting variable j back to 0 after the 1st loop. so the 2nd loop starts with a value of 10 for j, and hence, while loop is not executed.

```
//Second Section
System.out.println("\nEnter 10 numbers: ");
int j = 0;
while(j<10) {
    numArray2[j] = scanner.nextInt();
    j++;
} 
// add this
j = 0;

System.out.println("The entered numbers are: ");
while(j<10) {
    System.out.print(numArray2[j] + " ");
    j++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When you use last for loop j value is 10 in the beginning of that loop
> as you declare j out of the scope.So you should declare new variable
> and replace while loop from it.The other thing is you should use for
> loop to showing array2.Normally we use while loops for only when we
> not knowing about end time.So we use for loop for this.

```
//Second Section
System.out.println("\nEnter 10 numbers: ");
int j = 0;
while(j<10) {
    numArray2[j] = scanner.nextInt();
    j++;
}

System.out.println("The entered numbers are: ");
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    System.out.print(numArray2[i] + " ");
}
```